# Getting Redis Error ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes

Tags: redis, bitnami, redis-cluster

I am trying to deploy redis in Kubernetes but getting a below error.

Error:

edis 06:34:26.04 Welcome to the Bitnami redis container
redis 06:34:26.04 Subscribe to project updates by watching https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis
redis 06:34:26.04 Submit issues and feature requests at https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis/issues
redis 06:34:26.05
redis 06:34:26.05 INFO  ==> ** Starting Redis setup **
redis 06:34:26.07 ERROR ==> The REDIS_PASSWORD environment variable is empty or not set. Set the environment variable ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes to allow the container to be started with blank passwords. This is recommended only for development.

I have also done with deployment config as below but still getting errors.

spec:
containers:
- image: artifactory.prod.cre.az-eastus2.hosting.nuautoco.com:443/tts-docker/bitnami/redis:6.2.6
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
command: ["redis-server","/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
name: redis
env:
- name: ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
value: "yes"

Would you please help me for any work round